# Azure Application Insight Telemetry for On-Premises web app

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-application-insights

I setup our on-premises **.NET application** running on **IIS** with Azure's Application Insights by following this [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/monitor-performance-live-website-now). and it has been working great.

From what I understand this is a non-intrusive, code-less monitoring method which designed to add onto application that is already deployed and running in Production.

Then I came across this article about [AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core).  It indicates this is needed for code base monitoring on .NET Core application.

I'm a little confused while Goolging around trying to find what is the different between two methods, does this mean they both really do the same thing and that `AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry()` is only needed for .NET Core?

Do I need to add this to my web .NET application because one sub component used is written using .NET Core?

Comment: If your application is .Net Framework, you just need to add the nuget package to get it working. If you have a .Net Core application, you need to use the `AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry` method in the Startup class.

Comment: Thanks @gunr2171, our web application is .NET framework 4.7.2 but we recently implemented a service component layer that is written in .NET Core.  So I guess as it stands now I don't get any telemetries from that component unless I do what you suggested which is to add the telemetry method into that component's services collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments mentioned by gunr2171, I summarized the answer(for community members) below:

If the application is .Net Framework, we just need to [download and run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/monitor-performance-live-website-now#download) "Application Insights Status Monitor" and follow the steps in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/monitor-performance-live-website-now) which provided by Fylix. This solution is codeless but just for .Net Framework and deployed on IIS(shown as below screenshot)
[image]

If the application is .Net Core, we need to follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core), add "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" sdk to the project and use "AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry" in Startup class. We can also customize the Application Insights SDK in ConfigureServices() method of Startup.cs class.

Comment: Thanks @HuryShen for summarizing the answer nicely for everyone.  I'll accept it as the answer

Comment: The referred document is about Status Monitor, which is no longer the recommended approach for on-prem. Please use this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/status-monitor-v2-overview

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to enable Application Insights to an application:

1. Code-Less approach - used typically when the application is already deployed and running (in Azure or On-prem). This approach requires no modification to source code. There are limited customization available.

Code-Less approach is supported in Azure Web Apps for Asp.Net and Asp.Net Core apps. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-web-apps?tabs=net) with upcoming support for other languages like Java, Node.Js, Python.

Code-Less approach is supported in Azure VMs for Asp.Net (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-vm-vmss-apps)

Code-Less approach is supported in any on-prem server for Asp.Net Apps.(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/status-monitor-v2-overview)

2. Code-based approach - used source code is accessible, and typically involved adding a nuget package (in .NET world), and 1-2 lines of code. This offers maximum customization and also ability to send custom telemetry. Its almost immaterial where the actual application is run - it can be in Azure or On-Prem or anywhere.

If you are having an Asp.Net Core application, then the only place where code-less approach is supported is in Azure Web Apps. For every other places, you need to code-based approach (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core)

If you are having Asp.Net application, code-less is supported in Azure Web Apps, Azure VMs, On-Prem. You can still use code-based approach (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net), if you want to customize the telemetry collection.